# C arrays calling functions

Tags: c

below is my code for your reference. Rx_Buf contains one of the two values from Rfid_Tag[][]. I am getting tht value from another function and I want to find and confirm. the problem is its not working. Rfid_Tag[][] has different values i.e. its corrupted. I am not sure how a global variable defined is getting corrupted. I tried declaring it const, extern still the same problem.When i run this as standalone program it works perfectly, but when I call this function from main.c its not working. Can anyone pleasee help me with this.

Thanks

```
#define NUMBER_OF_RFID_TAGS 2
#define RFID_DATA_LENGTH    17

unsigned char  Rfid_Tag[NUMBER_OF_RFID_TAGS][RFID_DATA_LENGTH]= {
    {0x96,0x12,0xf1,0x6e,0xda,0x57,0x98,0x02,0x00,0xe1,0x50,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x11},
    {0x96,0x72,0xe9,0x6e,0xda,0x2f,0x98,0x02,0x00,0xe1,0x50,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x11}
};

int RFID_check(char *Rx_Buf)
{
    //unsigned char ucRfidReceivedData[RFID_DATA_LENGTH]= *Rx_Buf; //{0x00,0x01,0x2,0x03,0x04,0x5,0x06,0x07,0x8,0x09,0x0A,0xB,0x0C,0x0D,0xE,0x0F,0x10}; 
    unsigned count = 0;
    int found = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_RFID_TAGS; i++){
        count = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < RFID_DATA_LENGTH; j++){
            if(Rfid_Tag[i][j] == Rx_Buf[j]){
                count++;
                //PORTR.DIR = 0xff;
                //PORTR.OUTTGL = 0xff;
            }

        }
        if(count == RFID_DATA_LENGTH){

            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(found == true){
        PORTR.DIR = 0xff;
        PORTR.OUTTGL = 0x0f;
        RFID_accept();

    }
    else{
        RFID_error();
        PORTR.DIR = 0xff;
        PORTR.OUTTGL = 0x00;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It probably gets corrupted because somewhere you write to it. You can try to mark it as `const` and see if you get any compiler errors/warnings, and if not then keep it `const` but use a memory debugger such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to find writes to the array.

Comment: What are you passing in Rx_Buf[]?

Comment: values from RFID card which is same as in Rfid_Tag[][].

Comment: Post a short `main.c` file which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Post full code to remove any confusions.

Comment: How are you calling `RFID_check`?

Comment: int main(){ while(1){ RFID_read(); RFID_check(Rx_Buf);}}